# Should one set the paper size twice, when using KOMA-script and geometry?

Tags: koma-script, geometry, paper-size

This question continues my [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426059/is-it-possible-to-adjust-page-margins-in-koma-script-like-done-in-the-geometry-p).

My code:

```
\documentclass[paper = a4, pagesize, usegeometry = true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 5mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

  \section{Test section}
    Test text.

\end{document}
```

Intuitive is it enough to set the paper size globally as the document class option. But I wish to know it for sure. How is it?

Thank you for your effort in advance!

Comment: From the documentation: "Once you set option `usegeometry`, `typearea` tries to translate all of its options into options of `geometry`." Additional remarks: `paper=a4` is default for all KOMA-Script classes. Since KOMA-Script version 3.17 option `pagesize` is default, too. So can remove it from the class options. You only need: `\documentclass[usegeometry=true]{scrartcl}` and `\usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}`.